# java display in a JTextField component

Tags: java, swing

I am new in java programming and I would like to know how can I add the statement `cboDisplayList.getItemAt(4)` to the program code below so that the fifth item in the list is displayed in a `JTextField` component.

```
 package pkTopic5T6;
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.Color;
 import java.awt.Font;
 public class Topic5T6
{
public JComboBox cboDisplayList;
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Topic5T6 My56 = new Topic5T6();
    My56.go();
}
public void go()
{
    GUI56 My56 = new GUI56();
    populateList Mypop = new populateList();
    Mypop.grabItems();
}
class GUI56 extends JFrame
{
    JLabel lblHeading;
    protected  GUI56()
    {
        this.setSize(600,500);
        this.setLocation(100,100);
        this.setTitle("56");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLayout(null);
        Font f1 = new Font("Monospaced",Font.BOLD,32);
        Font f2 = new Font("Dialog",Font.BOLD,32);
        lblHeading = new JLabel("Testing Combo");
        lblHeading.setBounds(10,10,300,50);
        lblHeading.setFont(f2);
        this.add(lblHeading);
        cboDisplayList = new JComboBox();
        cboDisplayList.setBounds(10,70,300,50);
        cboDisplayList.setBackground(Color.PINK);
        cboDisplayList.setFont(f1);
        this.add(cboDisplayList);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
class populateList
{
    protected int k;
    protected populateList()
    {}
    protected void grabItems()
    {
        for (k=1; k<= 20; k =k+1)
        {
            cboDisplayList.addItem("Dummy Item " + k);
        }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is it displaying right now?

Comment: a drop down box with Dummy Item 1 up to 20

Comment: now on selecting any one?

Comment: Please validate from my post.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are first displaying JFrame and then populating data in combobox. If you are adding a textfield in GUI56 constructor and get the content in combobox, it will print null only, since you have not populated any value in combo box. So setText should be called after populating value in combo box. please see my solution.

```
package pkTopic5T6;
 import javax.swing.*;

import org.omg.CORBA.PUBLIC_MEMBER;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
 public class Topic5T6
{
public JComboBox cboDisplayList;
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Topic5T6 My56 = new Topic5T6();
    My56.go();
}
public void go()
{
    GUI56 My56 = new GUI56();
    populateList Mypop = new populateList();
    Mypop.grabItems();
    My56.addText1();
    System.out.println("end");
}
class GUI56 extends JFrame
{
    JLabel lblHeading;
    JTextField  textField;
    protected  GUI56()
    {
        this.setSize(600,500);
        this.setLocation(100,100);
        this.setTitle("56");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLayout(null);
        Font f1 = new Font("Monospaced",Font.BOLD,32);
        Font f2 = new Font("Dialog",Font.BOLD,32);
        lblHeading = new JLabel("Testing Combo");
        lblHeading.setBounds(10,10,300,50);
        lblHeading.setFont(f2);
        this.add(lblHeading);
        cboDisplayList = new JComboBox();
        cboDisplayList.setBounds(10,70,300,50);
        cboDisplayList.setBackground(Color.PINK);
        cboDisplayList.setFont(f1);
        this.add(cboDisplayList);
        textField=new JTextField("test");
       // this.add(new JTextField(cboDisplayList.getItemAt(0)+" test"));
         this.setVisible(true);

    }
    public void addText1()
    {

         textField.setText(cboDisplayList.getItemAt(4)+"");
         textField.setBounds(20,150,180,90);
         textField.setVisible(true);
         System.out.println("set text");
        this.add(textField);
    }
}
class populateList
{
    protected int k;
    protected populateList()
    {}
    protected void grabItems()
    {
        for (k=1; k<= 20; k =k+1)
        {
            cboDisplayList.addItem("Dummy Item " + k);
        }
       }
    }
}
```

I have used another method addText1() to add a textfield in the frame and is invoked after populating the data in combobox. cboDisplayList.getItemAt(4) will return the item in the combobox at position 4 as object and cboDisplayList.getItemAt(4)+"" will cast it as string

Comment: I have tested this and was getting the expected result

Comment: -1, yes it may work, but it is still a terrible design. You are still using unnecessary classes and invoking multiple methods from different classes. You need a PhD to understand the logic flow. This is such a complex solution for a simple problem.

Comment: but why can't we access addtext1() to object Mypop , i.e. Mypop.addtext1() and define the method addtext1() in the class populateList below after the method grabItems()

Answer (score 0):

There is a `setText` method for setting the text for `JTextField`

Comment: thanks but i did this and it is not working:



<<< item = cboDisplayList.getItemAt(4);
    txf4 = new JTextField("item");
    txf4.setBounds(10,70,300,50);
    this.add(txf4);
    txf4.setText("item");